# Generated string names in Calculated Properties aren't accepted by select cmdlet

Tags: powershell, select-object

I want to generate the following table:

```
AAA BBB CCC
--- --- ---
 10  10  10
 10  10  10
 10  10  10
 10  10  10
 10  10  10
```

So I write the following code using a `foreach` loop to generate the column names:

```
$property = @('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') | foreach {
    @{ name = $_; expression = { 10 } }
}
@(1..5) | select -Property $property
```

But I get the following error saying the `name` is not a `string`:

```
select : The "name" key has a type, System.Management.Automation.PSObject, that is not valid; expected type is System.String.
At line:4 char:11
+ @(1..5) | select -Property $property
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegalValue2,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

To get the code work, I have to convert the `$_` to `string` like below:

```
$property = @('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') | foreach {
    @{ name = [string]$_; expression = { 10 } }
}
@(1..5) | select -Property $property
```

Or like below:

```
$property = @('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') | foreach {
    @{ name = $_; expression = { 10 } }
}
$property | foreach { $_.name = [string]$_.name }
@(1..5) | select -Property $property
```

The question is: the `$_` is already a `string`. Why do I have to convert it to `string` again? And why `select` thinks that the `name` is `PSObject`?

To confirm that it's already a `string`, I write the following code to print the type of `name`:

```
$property = @('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC') | foreach {
    @{ name = $_; expression = { 10 } }
}
$property | foreach { $_.name.GetType() }
```

The following result confirms that it's already a `string`:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------            
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
True     True     String                                   System.Object       
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

I know that there are many other easier ways to generate the table. But I want to understand why I have to convert a `string` to `string` to make the code work, and why `select` doesn't think that the `string` is a `string`. For what it's worth, my `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` is:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  1474
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the **unfortunate effects of incidental, normally *invisible* `[psobject]` wrappers** PowerShell uses behind the scenes.

In your case, because the input strings are supplied *via the pipeline*, they get wrapped in and stored *as `[psobject]` instances* in your hashtables, which is the cause of the problem.

The workaround - which is neither obvious nor should it be necessary - is to **discard the wrapper by accessing `.psobject.BaseObject`**:

```
$property = 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC' | ForEach-Object {
    @{ name = $_.psobject.BaseObject; expression = { 10 } }
}
1..5 | select -Property $property
```

Note:

- In your case, a simpler alternative to `.psobject.BaseObject` (see the conceptual [about_Intrinsic Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members) help topic) would have been to call `.ToString()`, given that you want a string.
- To test a given value / variable for the presence of such a wrapper, use `-is [psobject]`; with your original code, the following yields `$true`, for instance:

  - `$property[0].name -is [psobject]`
  - Note, however, that this test is meaningless for `[pscustomobject]` instances, where it is *always* `$true` (custom objects are in essence `[psobject]` instances without a .NET base objects - they only have dynamic properties).

**That the normally invisible `[psobject]` wrappers *situationally, obscurely* result in behavioral differences is arguably a *bug* and the subject of [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579)**.

---

**Simpler and faster alternative**, using the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```
$property = ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC').ForEach({
  @{ name = $_; expression = { 10 } }
})
1..5 | select -Property $property
```

**Unlike the pipeline, the `.ForEach()` *method* does *not* wrap `$_` in `[psobject]`**, so the problem doesn't arise and no workaround is needed.

Using the method is also *faster*, although note that, unlike the pipeline, it must collect all its input in memory up front (clearly not a problem with an array literal).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accidentally hit enter when typing reply (wanted to separate follow-up questions to different lines) so I deleted my previous reply. Your update and the GitHub link addressed these questions before I could finish typing them :)