# What does T<T> (e.g. System.Collections.Queue<byte>) mean in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, generics, powershell-core

I had Windows PowerShell script that initialized a queue like this:

```
$queue = New-Object System.Collections.Queue<byte>
```

The code was working fine in Windows PowerShell, but it does not in PowerShell [Core]. It fails with

> Cannot find type [System.Collections.Queue<byte>]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

When fixing the script for PowerShell [Core], I've realized that:

1. `System.Collections.Queue` is not a generic type (`System.Collections.Generic.Queue` is).
2. Generic type syntax in PowerShell is `[]`, not `<>`.

So the correct code, both in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core] is:

```
$queue = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Queue[byte]
```

But now I wonder what was my original code actually doing. What magic is behind that? Is my new code a real equivalent of the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is that ***Windows PowerShell* simply *quietly ignores* the `<byte>` part**; in fact, it doesn't matter what is inside `<` and `>`, and more generally, there are several characters that can start a suffix that is ignored, such as `!`, `@` and `%`.

In other words: this is a ***bug***, and it has since been **fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, which properly interprets the *whole* argument as the type name.

And, as you note:

- *Generic type arguments* always require enclosure in `[...]` in PowerShell as well as the underlying, *language-agnostic .NET APIs*.

  - `[...]` enclosure is also used for PowerShell's *type literals*, which are a *superset* of the notation understood by the .NET APIs, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093924/45375).
  - Because in v5+ the **static `::new()` method** can be used on type literals as a method-syntax alternative to [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object), your generic-queue construction command can also be written as:

    ```
    $queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[byte]]::new()
    ```

    - This expression-mode way of calling constructors via `::new()` is preferable to `New-Object` calls for several reasons:

      - It avoids the pitfalls of argument-mode parsing, especially with the frequently seen *pseudo-method syntax* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76615570/45375) for an example.
      - It avoids the `[psobject]` wrappers that `New-Object` wraps newly constructed objects in, which are *usually* invisible and benign, but on occasion cause problems - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67843770/45375) for an example.
      - With repeated calls (such as in a loop), it performs better than `New-Object`
- By contrast, the `<...>` syntax is *language-specific*, as notably used in C#.

Answer (score 1):

A type syntax in PowerShell is **always** `[T]`, not `<T>`.

See e.g. [`Queue<T> Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-8.0)…
Here `<>` are *meta brackets*: in Microsoft conception,
`<Text inside angle brackets>` means a *placeholder for which you must supply a value*.

The following example comes from PowerShell 5 under `wt.exe` (*Windows Terminal*):

```
PS D:\PShell> [System.Collections.Generic.Queue
Comparer<>             IEqualityComparer<>    LinkedListNode<>
Dictionary<>           IList<>                List<>
EqualityComparer<>     IReadOnlyCollection<>  Queue<>
HashSet<>              IReadOnlyDictionary<>  SortedDictionary<>
ICollection<>          IReadOnlyList<>        SortedList<>
IComparer<>            ISet<>                 SortedSet<>
IDictionary<>          KeyNotFoundException   Stack<>
IEnumerable<>          KeyValuePair<>
IEnumerator<>          LinkedList<>

Class System.Collections.Generic.Queue[T]
```

As a picture:

[image]